# Yaml file under src does not load when Junit testing in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit

I am new to spring boot.

I have a Service class as below

```
@Service
public class AService{
    @Value("${sample.time})
    private Long time;
    ...
    public int sampleMethod(){
        ...
       return time;
     }
}
```

and my application.yml under src/resource has:

```
sample:
    time:1
```

and my junit test class is:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(classes = MainApplication.class)
public class AServiceTest{
    @Autowired
   private WebApplicationContext wac;

   private Aservice aservice;

  @Before
  public void setupMockMvc() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    aservice = new AService();
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).build();
  }
  public void sampleMethodTest(){
    Assert.assertEquals(1,aservice.sampleMethod());
  }
```

This always gives false, because the method `aservice.sampleMethod()` Returns `0`.
It is not able to read the **yml** file under src when am testing.
I know that since ist injected with spring by standalone like this wont work. But it would be great help if you could guide me with possible Solutions or any pointers are helpful too.

Thanks in advance

Comment: is it a syntax error : @Value("${sample.time}") not closing the string?

Comment: I just missed it writing here! Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is due to `new AService()`. remove `new AService()` and use autowired AService.

Try below:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(classes = MainApplication.class)
public class AServiceTest{
    @Autowired
   private WebApplicationContext wac;
    @Autowired
   private Aservice aservice;

  @Before
  public void setupMockMvc() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).build();
  }
  public void sampleMethodTest(){
    Assert.assertEquals(1,aservice.sampleMethod());
   }
```

Comment: Thanks alot Bharath... This works... U saved my day...Can you Point to any links which explains about this..

Comment: @pgman see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null

Comment: @bharath, though this works. now if i do any Mocks using Mock... Mocks arent working. If i remove Autowired then Mocks works but noth the yaml file. Is there any configuration am missing?

Comment: i.e., when i use @Mock to mock an instance... it isnt working when autowired is used

Comment: @pgman if you use ```@Mock``` then you have to define its mocked behaviour it will never load the value

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your .yaml file available under /src/test/resources too in order for tests to be able to access these properties.

This will also enable you to set test specific properties.

Comment: Thx for Reply.. I forgot to mention i have added same file under test/resources too